# What are the inbuilt methods in python while declaring class like "__init__" and "__str__"?

Tags: python, python-class

This are the default methods. Which are other default methods?

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def __str__(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Call `dir` on an object to see all the methods it implements, including those inherited from its superclass (including `object`).

Comment: What makes you thing those are defaults? Especially the `__str__` one with just `pass`, which would cause a TypeError if you tried to print such an object.

Answer (score 1):

They are explained at [this document](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames). Also `dir()` can show names methods of class.

Comment: Thanks.! dir() is very useful.